# making daemonset node initialisation pod run only once per node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to run an initialisation script on each node, and I want to run them only once.

Here I have the yaml to do some basic initialisation on each node, but once the initialisation script finish execution, the pod exits with `exit code: 0` and the daemonset restarts the pod, running the initialisation script again and again.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-cr
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-sa
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-init-node-cr
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-init-node-sa
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-sa
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: test-init-node
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test-init-node
      app.kubernetes.io/component: configurator
  # replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-init-node
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: test-init-node
        app.kubernetes.io/component: configurator
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: k8s.amazee.io/node-configured
                operator: DoesNotExist
      hostPID: true
      hostNetwork: true
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      serviceAccount: test-init-node-sa
      containers:
      - name: init
        env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        command: 
        - nsenter
        - --mount=/proc/1/ns/mnt
        - --
        - bash
        - -xc
        - |
          echo "starting the magic"
          echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
          echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 

        image: alpine/k8s:1.28.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 50M
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true
```

Is there any way for me to prevent the daemonset from restarting the pod if the pod exits?
i.e. ensuring that the initialisation only happen once per node.

I tried adding a preStop but it does not seem to have any effect.
The idea is that if `k8s.amazee.io/node-configured` is set then the daemonset will not schedule onto that node.

```
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh"
              - -c
              - kubectl label node "$MY_NODE_NAME" k8s.amazee.io/node-configured=$(date +%s)
```

neither does adding a semicolon (well this is expected but I thought why not give it a try)

```
        command: 
        - nsenter
        - --mount=/proc/1/ns/mnt
        - --
        - bash
        - -xc
        - |
          echo "starting the magic"
          echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
          echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
        - ; 
        - /bin/sh"
        - -c
        - kubectl label node "$MY_NODE_NAME" k8s.amazee.io/node-configured=$(date +%s)
```

Is there any way for me to prevent the daemonset from restarting the pod if the pod exits properly? i.e. ensuring that the initialisation only happen once per node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the daemonset pod works, but it will still take up some resource and does not feel elegant.

from @norbjd's answer, I saw this in the [GCP tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gke-init-daemonsets-tutorial).

```
initContainers:
    - image: ubuntu:18.04
      name: node-initializer
      command: ["/scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
      env:
        - name: ROOT_MOUNT_DIR
          value: /root
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
  containers:
    - image: "gcr.io/google-containers/pause:2.0"
      name: pause
```

The tutorial is talking about using the pause contain from google-containers to avoid a restart of the pod. However, what caught my eye was the `initContainers`.

[Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#understanding-init-containers):

```
Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:

Init containers always run to completion.
Each init container must complete successfully before the next one starts.
```

This gave me an idea. What if I ran 2 containers, the first being an `initContainers` that does all the initialisations, and the second `containers` will run a command to add a label to prevent scheduling, hence stopping any further pod creation/restart of the Daemonset for that particular node.

Of course, by the same logic, both can be `initContainers`, but in my case I used 1 `initContainers` and 1 `containers`, since `containers` will wait for all `initContainers` to be completed so they have the same result as both `initContainers`.

working example

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-cr
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-sa
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-init-node-cr
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-init-node-sa
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-init-node-sa
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: test-init-node
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test-init-node
      app.kubernetes.io/component: configurator
  # replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test-init-node
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: test-init-node
        app.kubernetes.io/component: configurator
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: test-init-node-date
                operator: DoesNotExist
      hostPID: true
      hostNetwork: true
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      serviceAccount: test-init-node-sa
      initContainers:
      - name: init
        command:         
        - nsenter
        - --mount=/proc/1/ns/mnt
        - --
        - bash
        - -xc
        - |
          echo "starting the magic"
          echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
          echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
          echo "user00   soft  core    unlimited" >>  /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf 
        image: alpine/k8s:1.28.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 50M
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true

      containers: 
      - name: add-label-to-remove-scheduling
        env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          kubectl label node "$MY_NODE_NAME" test-init-node-date=$(date +%s) 
        image: alpine/k8s:1.28.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 50M
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true
```

Rough Explanation:

1. create the relevant service account and permissions
2. check if the `test-init-node-date` label is set. If it is, skip and
   do nothing
3. create the `initContainers` and run the init
   script as needed
4. create the `Containers` and add `test-init-node-date` label

sample labels:

```
kubernetes.io/os=linux
node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n2d-standard-8
test-init-node-date=1693280374
```

This will then create a daemonset that runs the init pod once, start another pod to add `test-init-node-date` label. Since the `test-init-node-date` label is set, no new pods will be scheduled by the daemonset.

And finally, to quote norbjd, to prevent accidental re-run of the init script(e.g. someone deleted the label), you can add a safeguard check before you run the script.

```
if [ ! -f /etc/game-conf-limits-updated ]
then
    echo "starting the magic"
    echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf
    echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf

    touch /etc/game-conf-limits-updated
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I had the same issue few months ago, I don't know if this is the best solution, but at least it works. I've made some research though, and couldn't find a built-in solution, so I ended up with this.*

*EDIT: it looks like even GCP resort to this solution: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gke-init-daemonsets-tutorial.*

The solution is to:

1. make the script inside the daemonset know when the script has already been executed. So that if it restarts, you can just skip the steps
2. make the script sleep for infinity after executing. This ensure that the daemonset will not restart (unless it's killed, but 1st point will avoid the steps being re-executed)

In your specific case, you can transform your script:

```bash
echo "starting the magic"
echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf
echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf
```

to:

```bash
if [ ! -f /etc/game-conf-limits-updated ]
then
    echo "starting the magic"
    echo "*   hard  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf
    echo "*   soft  core    unlimited" >> /etc/security/limits.d/game.conf

    touch /etc/game-conf-limits-updated
fi

sleep infinity
```

The `/etc/game-conf-limits-updated` will exist only if the script has been executed once. As I said above, the `sleep infinity` will prevent the daemonset to restart the pod. But if it restarts for some reason, checking if `/etc/game-conf-limits-updated` exists (`[ ! -f /etc/game-conf-limits-updated ]`) will avoid writing again in `/etc/security/limits.d/game.conf`. And the script will sleep for infinity, avoiding a restart.

Instead of checking if `/etc/game-conf-limits-updated` exists (and writing a file on your node filesystem), you can also check if the label is set on your node. This is maybe more elegant.

Note that in [GCP tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gke-init-daemonsets-tutorial), they use a pod with an init container and a `pause` container. This is equivalent to my solution with a single container.

The only downside of this is your daemonset pod will run forever on your node.

A better solution would be to configure your node directly (e.g. using custom images for your cluster nodes with already updated files as you wish), but I don't know if it's possible with GKE.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have done a solution based on your reply and it solved my problem!